# How can I compute the average number of a nested list in Python?

Tags: python-3.x

I have a list:
a = [[1,2,3],[4,5,6],[7,8,9]]

And I want the average of the 3rd element of each list: (3 + 6 + 9)

Which function should i create in order to do this??

Answer (score 1):

It is always better to let others know what you have tried yourself when asking questions on Stackoverflow.

Anyway, try the below code:

```
def third_avg(a_list):

    list_of_third = [i[2] for i in a_list]
    return sum(list_of_third)/len(list_of_third)

print(third_avg([[1,2,3],[4,5,6],[7,8,9]]))
```

Output:

```
6.0
```

This function basically creates a new list with only the third values of the sublists. Then returns the average (`sum of all elements/num of elements`).